# How to get an instance of my view controller from the app delegate, storyboards, iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, pointers, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

Trying to "instantiate" my initial view controller from the app delegate. I trying to populate an NSMutableArray from the app delegate. A property of the view controller "myMutabelArray" gets an array that is created within the app delegate. With the code below the array is uneffected, even though it's count is 4 (has four objects), as created in the app delegate.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
controller.myMutableArray = mutableArrayCreatedInAppDelegate;
```

When I log the count from within the AppDelegate I get `4`.
When I log the count from within the ViewController I get `0`.

I also tried the following which makes me suspect that I am not getting a pointer to the view controller as needed.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[controller.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
```

It will return the initial view controller of the main storyboard.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That did it! Is there a particular reason that my code does not work to pass the data to my view controller?

Comment: You're welcome. The `instantiateInitialViewController` method creates a new instance of the initial view controller, which will be different from the one presented on the screen. You should use this method to switch to a storyboard other than the main one. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: now its -- self.view.window.rootViewController  where self is UIViewController